# Look for app in the store : cef error

Tags: windows-8, windows-error-reporting

We generally get error `Look for app in the store` when we click on an unknown file. But from last 3 weeks, I have been getting this error(**cef error)** **about every 20 seconds**. I don't know what happened. I turned off all app updates, but it didn't help. Google couldn't help me either. Do you have any idea why this occurs and how to fix this error?

Comment: Are you getting it perhaps when you download a file?  You need to describe the trigger event.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm getting this about every 20 seconds.....it's too irritating....

Comment: If you are getting it every 20 seconds then you have some process trying to access the file.  Boot into a minimal configuration and verify you don't get the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found solution. It's because of a software called `Softonic`, I've uninstalled it and every thing is working fine now.

Comment: Minute 56: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK3316 mentions Softonic being the culprit via Process Monitor.